# How to display sub string in reverse order but read from left to right in VBA

Tags: excel, vba

I am processing a .txt file in VBA.

Amongst other tasks, I need to read in a string representing a date and display the actual date in Excel.

A date string in the .txt file looks like "190223"
This represents 23/02/2019

My challenge is to get this done.

What I have done so far is:

```
' ... loop

With ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets(1)

' Other statements here

' Event date time
    .Range("N" & i).Value = StrReverse(Mid(.Range(keyword.Offset(0, 4).Address), 1, 2) & _
    "/" & Mid(.Range(keyword.Offset(0, 4).Address), 3, 2) & _ 
    "/" & Mid(.Range(keyword.Offset(0, 4).Address), 5, 2))

End With
```

But I get the undesired output:

```
32/20/91 ' For a date string 190223 the desired output should be 23/02/19
```

Any help would be much appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Are they all 6 character dates?

Comment: How will the code know that the year is 1919 or 2019 or 3019?

Comment: Thanks all for the quick response. These are all 6 character dates. All first 2 leading characters in the .txt dump file represent 2019 since the figure is generated for events of the current year.

Comment: @KingSufu Did you try the answer below?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

#### Convert it into a real date

You must extract year, month and day of that string and then convert this into a real date.

Then you can format the date to what ever date format you like. The value that is saved in the cell is then a real date value (not a string!) so you can calculate with it.

I highly recommend to read [How Dates Work in Excel – The Calendar System Explained + Video](https://www.excelcampus.com/functions/how-dates-work-in-excel/) to understand the background and why real dates are so important.

Here is an example:

```
Option Explicit

Public Sub ConvertDateExample()
    Const InputStr As String = "190223"

    Dim InputYear As Integer
    Dim InputMonth As Integer
    Dim InputDay As Integer

    'extract year, month and day
    InputYear = Left(InputStr, 2)
    InputMonth = Mid(InputStr, 3, 2)
    InputDay = Right(InputStr, 2)

    'put it together to a real date
    Dim RealDate As Date
    RealDate = DateSerial(InputYear, InputMonth, InputDay)

    'write the date into a cell
    Range("A1").Value = RealDate
    'format that cell to your desired format
    Range("A1").NumberFormat = "dd/mm/yyyy"
End Sub
```

Comment: It's a bit disappointing `VBA` doesn't have a source input format for `CDate` like some other languages do (e.g. `datetime` in python)

Comment: @Tom Well it just cannot know how to interpret a given string into a date, since there could be multiple possible solutions, so you need additional information if you want to convert a string into a date. The string itself is never sufficiant to convert it into a real date.

Comment: I understand that but in python I could do something like `datetime.striptime('190223', '%y%m%d').strftime('%d/%m/%y')` to achieve the same. I'm suggesting it's frustrating `VBA` doesn't have a way of passing the source format to the CDate function or something similar. e.g. `CDate("190223", "yymmdd")`

Comment: @Tom Ah well, that's true that would be handy. Actually when working with dates especially when strings come into the game it aways gets messy in VBA. Actually the worst is that the user can input what ever he want's and Excel starts guessing what he actually meant. There is no proper capability of a safe date input in Excel which makes using dates from user input a mess. Especially when different localizations are used all over the globalized world.

Comment: That's why I always recommend to **only** use [ISO 8601](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601) date format `YYYY-MM-DD hh:mm:ss` which is the only one that is internationally not misunderstood and can be read by human and computers without misunderstandings.

Comment: @Tom you can write a small fucntion `Function ConvertDate(InputString As String, InputFormat As String, OutputFormat As String) As Date` based on Pᴇʜ's example. And then you can use it as `ConvertDate "190223", "ymd", "dmy"` ;)

Comment: Thank you @PEH. Using your code as a user def function  does the work