# Changing Format of The Date That Has been Already Captured to the Excel

Tags: excel, vba, date, format

> *Update 05/03/2019*
>
> I used the following from the URL given below by Tom.
>
> ```
> Function ConvertDate(InputStr As String) As Date
>
>     Dim InputYear As Integer
>     Dim InputMonth As Integer
>     Dim InputDay As Integer
>
>     'extract year, month and day
>     InputYear = Right(InputStr, 4)
>     InputMonth = Mid(InputStr, 4, 2)
>     InputDay = Left(InputStr, 2)
>
>     'put it together to a real date
>     ConvertDate = DateSerial(InputYear, InputMonth, InputDay)
> End Function
> ```
>
> It gives me the date in the way I want. But when I write the same date
>   to a text file, the date changes back to the PC format which is
>   MM/DD/YYYY. Is there a way to get this solved?.

****I have this excel VBA code which captures the date from another mainframe application which has the format of DD.MM.YYYY Once its captured I'm trying to change it back to the following format YYYY/MM/DD. I have applied the following format to the date_value column of my excel. Sheet1.Range("A2", "A50000").NumberFormat = "yyyy/mm/dd" This is how I captured the date value from the mainframe program. Cells(noRow, 9).Value = Trim(MyHost.TextRC(5, 68, 12)) When I run the program it does not change the date format the way I want. My PC date format is set to the following, MM/DD/YYYY. Any hint or guidance is highly appreciated.****

Comment: Hi @SAMROX I would use a `Date` variable and the function `DateSerial` to input the date that way you can manually tell excel what is day, month and year and later it will be formated as you want because it will be holded into a Date variable.,

Comment: I doubt `.` is recognized as a date delimiter, so you're just getting a string. Just parse the date and use `DateSerial`.

Comment: This is very similar to a question that was asked yesterday take a look at [link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54883460/3042759)

Comment: Thank you all. It helped me to capture the date as the way I want. But I still have issue when I try to write the same data row to a text file.

Comment: Thanks for sharing the link. I did updated my code to capture the data as mentioned. It does not work when you saved it as a text file and it automatically gets converted to the PC format.